# Issue with the cross apply statement and from

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i'm triying to make something but i'm stuck on an issue. The problem is that i need to make a stored procedure where if a param of the procedure is the actual date or older, 2 params in a query and a part of the where would be ignored . I use initially an if else to ignore the cases but the code is repeated and inconsistent to maintain. So i need to make the same thing but without the if /else statement. any help would be apreciated.

```
select 
                Cats.*,
                Zone.[D] as [De], -- this part would be avoided if @Min and @Max are null
                Zone.[R] as [Re]  -- this part would be avoided if @Min and @Max are null
            from 
                flv
                CROSS APPLY  --all the cross apply would be avoided if @Min and @Max are null
                    (
                        select
                            x
                        from 
                            XXXX
                        where 
                            XXXX.IDx= 1
                    ) as Data
where           
                    ---where clause
```

I just want to avoid the cross apply in case that the 2 params are null

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  What is `Cats`?  What is `Zone`?  The `cross apply` isn't doing anything, except possibly filtering all rows.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff the idea is how I can avoid the definition of the 2 elements in the selet and the cross apply if the 2 params are null. The code is an example. sorry if don't have any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `XXXX.IDx= 1` into `@Min IS NOT NULL AND @Max IS NOT NULL AND XXXX.IDx= 1` and your cross apply won't hurt a bit. However it would mean no rows will be returned from the `CROSS APPLY` and thus the whole query. So you'll als need the `CROSS APPLY` into an `OUTER APPLY`

For example the following script:

```
DECLARE @test INT
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmpTable AS TT
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.test AS T
        WHERE @test IS NOT NULL
    ) AS T
```

Gives the following execution plan, pay special attention the the Filter component here.

[image]

When you hover the filter component you may notice the following

[image]

Meaning `dbo.test` in this case would only be scanned if the startup predicate is met. Put `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on you query and look at the actual query plan and the table is even not even in the query plan if `@test` is null.

[image]

Comment: mmm @MWillemse, don't work for me, when I put it, the query don't give me any values, I cotinue searching...

Comment: Changed your `CROSS APPLY` into an `OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: I changed, but now allways past the outer apply, return me the same results

Comment: Maybe you could setup a more concrete example.

Comment: thanks, I rewrite this part of the SP and works fine with the OUTER APPLY. Thanks again.